# Multiple post requests and small web server

Tags: javascript, post

I have a problem with a small web server with limited resources:

- The device is an embedded controller with network interface and uses web pages for configuration.
- The data are exchanged with `json` format and the post method.

The problem is this: my device can serve only one post request at a time with a small buffer size.

To test it, I created a page with multiple posts for sending data to my server. I opened the page with the browser Firefox 4.0 and the browser tried to open multiple socket to serve all requests in parallel.

How do I create a sequential flow message? (I'm not worried about the speed)

Here is a small example of how I intend to proceed, but this solution opens two sockets for sending two post requests to my server and aborts one of them.

```js
for (var j=0; j<2; j++) {
    // read page data and create objdata  
    jdata = JSON.stringify(objdata);

    // alert("I am about to POST this:\n\n" + jdata);

   $.post(
     'prgtimetbl.json',
     jdata,
     function(data) {
     //           alert("Response: " + data);
     },
     "json"
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and `async: false`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    async: false,
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cixate was faster than me, but I had a slightly different approach using async queued requests.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/HTGPM/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var stuffToPost = [{name:'obj1',id:1},{name:'obj2',id:2},{name:'obj3',id:3}];
    var postIndex = 0;

    var postNext = function() {
        if (postIndex < stuffToPost.length)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '?',
                data: JSON.stringify(stuffToPost[postIndex]),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('Data '+stuffToPost[postIndex].id+' was sent successfully');
                    postIndex++;
                    postNext();
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Something bad happened. Stopping');
                }
            });
        }
        else if (postIndex == stuffToPost.length)
        {
            alert('All data is sent !');
        }
    };

    postNext();
});
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the quick response using the suggestions I solved !